# kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': Cannot load such file

Tags: file, load

When I execute, I am getting an error:                           `64x/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/Kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': Cannot load such file`

```
     require "net/http"
     require "uri"
     require "nokogiri"

     uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
     response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
     puts parse_body(response.body)

     def parse_body(response)
      begin
          return Nokogiri::XML(response) { |config| config.strict }
          rescue Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError => e
          return "caught exception: #{e}"
      end
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `require_relative` generally when ever you get this issue. (not the best way though!)

Try this

`$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ".")`